# AVRoutePickerView shows incorrect output device information when changing AVAudioSession's mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudiosession

I have a question related to `AVAudioSession`’s mode. I’m working on a video-conference app. When the user is on an audio call and he/she escalates to video, we change the `AVAudioSession` mode from `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` to `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat`. The problem is that because of that change, we are experienced this bug in the `AVRoutePickerView` list of output devices:

> 1. Connect iPhone to Bluetooth headsets.
> 2. User A make audio call to user B with audio though Bluetooth.
> 3. User A switches output device to Speaker.
> 4. User A escalate to video -> Active audio displayed as speaker but audio device list shows Bluetooth headsets.
> 5. User A de-escalate to audio-> Active audio displayed as speaker but audio device list shows Bluetooth headsets.

If we comment the line of code that switches the `AVAudioSession`’s mode, the problem is gone. In Apple docs says that `AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat` “reduces the set of allowable audio routes to only those appropriate for video chat”, and “has the side effect of enabling the `AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth`  category option”. Because of that, I see a correlation between the mode set and the bug, but also I think that it’s the correct mode for video chat.

So the question is, has anyone had the same or similar problem? Any recommendation?

Comment: still not very sure what the exact problem is.. when switching to AVAudioSessionModeVideoChat audio device "Bluetooth headset" ends up in the device list as expected as side effect, when switching back its still there, and still was expected as sideeffect..

Comment: The problem is that the audio output for the call is still the Speaker, but the selected output in the `AVRoutePickerView` is the Bluetooth headset. There is a misinformation in what the `AVRoutePickerView` is informing to the user and what is the real audio output.

Comment: maybe a nice hint is.. what microphone is the videochat using when the headset doesn't have a mic as they usually do. and how should the routing look like then.. because this would lead to the assumption that mic and speaker are going different routes. or i am wrong?